# search a mongodb record which has "." (dot) in record name

Tags: regex, mongodb-query

Record in database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b97b20e7b473d1ee468a972"),
    "name" : "insearch.com wiki",
    "description" : "insearch",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-11T12:16:14.181Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-11T12:16:14.181Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Search Query

```
db.getCollection('contents').find({name:{$regex: '.', $options: "i"}})
```

How can I search the record when I give "." (only dot operator) in search box.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` period character has special meaning in a regex where it matches any character. To disable that behavior and match against the period itself, you need to escape it:

```
db.getCollection('contents').find({name:{$regex: '\\.', $options: "i"}})
```

To do this programmatically (as in your case with a search box), see [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)